# Sinatra cookies not acting as expected

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
before %(/(..)/.*) do
    lang = params[:captures].first
    cookies[:lang] = lang
    p cookies
end

get '/' do
    p cookies
end
```

The above code is expected to set the cookie `lang` with the a two character value on any requests `/xx/*` where `xx` is any two character string. This works as expected, as navigating `/es/login` will output `<#Sinatra::Cookies::Jar: "ASP.NET_SessionId"=>"*snip*", "lang"=>"es">`.

If I immediately navigate to `/`, it outputs `<#Sinatra::Cookies::Jar: "ASP.NET_SessionId"=>"..", "lang"=>"en">`

This is strange for a number of reason, most notably that I never navigated to `/en/*`. I'm assuming `cookies[:lang]` isn't properly setting the cookie, and `en` is a value that was properly set to `lang` some time in the past, but I don't know any ways to check that, or fix it.

I should note this is the only place I touch the `cookies` object in the project.

A snippet of the initialization file:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/cookies'
...
class Site < Sinatra::Application
    helpers Sinatra::Cookies
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that cookies are path specific.

For example, `/en/login` would have it's own set of cookies that applies to `/en/login/*`, while `/` would have cookies that applied to `/*`. So by setting `cookies[:lang]` in `before %r(/(..)/.*)`, I was only setting the cookie for any route `/xx/*`.

I solved this by using Sinatra's `response.set_cookie` method, which allowed me to explicitly set the path to `/`. I could have also set the Cookies gem's default settings to `/`, but I thought that was a poor idea.

Solution with `sinatra#set_cookie`:

```
before $(/(..)/.* do
    lang = params[:captures].first
    response.set_cookie(:lang, lang)
end
```

Solution by setting the defaults on Cookies

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/cookies'
...
def Site < Sinatra::Application
    helpers Sinatra::Cookies
    configure do
        set :cookie_options, domain: nil
    end
    ...
end
```